# Platforms calculating epoch start/end timestamps off by 1 second?

Tags: epoch

I've seen this many times now and I believe it's wrong, or at least strange. I'd like to see what you folks have to say.

Let's take a look at any random epoch, say 400, and request Koios, Blockfrost and Cardanoscan to get the start/end timestamps.

They all show the same timestamps: `1679003091` to `1679435091`. This suggests timestamp `1679003091` is the first and `1679435091` the last second of epoch 400, doesn't it?

At the time of writing, an epoch is configured to have 432,000 slots and each slot equals one second. Since slots are the smallest entity we don't need to care about milliseconds.

How do these platforms calculate the timestamps: I believe they take the genesis block timestamp of epoch 0 at `2017/09/23 21:44:51` and keep adding 432,000 seconds. Yes, I am aware Byron era had a different slot configuration, but it doesn't matter here as the result is the exact same length in terms of time (432,000 seconds per epoch).

This doesn't seem wrong on the first glance. But timestamp `1679435091` of epoch 400 is the first second of that epoch, so it counts as 1, not 0. Adding 432,000 seconds to 1 results in 432,001 seconds.

Let's take a look at epoch 401 now. We find the epoch's start timestamp to be the exact same as the end timestamp of the previous epoch. This seems wrong. Epochs don't overlap.

Shouldn't we treat the first slot of an epoch as 0? It'd result in a clean continuation of time without bleeding into the next epoch.